# SBT dependency conflict between two specs2's versions jars?

Tags: scala, playframework, sbt, specs2

I upgraded play framework to version 2.4, but in my jars file I still see specs2 version 2.4.13 jars that I did not understand their origin, since play framework 2.4 uses specs2 independently this caused a version conflict.

I tried to determine which dependency is calling specs2 version 2.4.13 implicitly with this plugin:

```
addSbtPlugin("net.virtual-void" % "sbt-dependency-graph" % "0.10.0-RC1")
```

but it did not resolve the ptoblem.

The output of `dependencyTree` task:

```
         +-com.github.nscala-time:nscala-time_2.11:2.2.0 [S]
[info]         | +-joda-time:joda-time:2.8.2
[info]         | +-org.joda:joda-convert:1.2
[info]         | 
[info]         +-com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:1.3.9
[info]         +-com.google.guava:guava:18.0
[info]         +-com.madgag:scala-io-file_2.11:0.4.10-itb [S]
[info]         | +-com.madgag:scala-io-core_2.11:0.4.10-itb [S]
[info]         | | +-com.jsuereth:scala-arm_2.11:2.0 [S]
[info]         | | 
[info]         | +-org.scala-lang.modules:scala-parser-combinators_2.11:1.0.5 [S]
[info]         | 
[info]         +-log4j:log4j:1.2.17
[info]         +-net.htmlparser.jericho:jericho-html:3.3
[info]         +-net.sourceforge.htmlcleaner:htmlcleaner:2.2
[info]         +-org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.3.2
[info]         +-org.scalaz:scalaz-core_2.11:7.1.3 [S]
[info]         | +-org.scala-lang.modules:scala-parser-combinators_2.11:1.0.4 (evicted by: 1.0.5)
[info]         | +-org.scala-lang.modules:scala-parser-combinators_2.11:1.0.5 [S]
[info]         | +-org.scala-lang.modules:scala-xml_2.11:1.0.4 (evicted by: 1.0.6)
[info]         | +-org.scala-lang.modules:scala-xml_2.11:1.0.6 [S]
[info]         | 
[info]         +-xalan:serializer:2.7.2
```

the origin error is : 
*** After upgrade, I added to the build sbt file the specs2 dependency, as a result I got 2 versions of jars file and in test file
`class testSpec extends Specification with Forms`

read Specification from specs version 3.6.6 and read Forms from version  2.4.13 ***

Comment: Which error do you actually get? What is the output of the `dependencyTree` task?

Comment: @cbley, I eidted the question

Comment: Ah, silly me. You have to run the task for the `Test` scope, of course. What does `test:dependencyTree` give you?

Comment: @cbley I got the following:  the org.specs it is not under any other dependency
 +-org.specs2:specs2-core_2.11:2.4.13 [S]
[info]   | +-org.specs2:specs2-matcher_2.11:2.4.13 [S]
[info]   |   +-org.specs2:specs2-common_2.11:2.4.13 [S]
[info]   |     +-org.scala-lang:scala-reflect:2.11.4 [S]
[info]   |     +-org.scalaz:scalaz-concurrent_2.11:7.1.0 [S]
[info]   |     | +-org.scalaz:scalaz-core_2.11:7.1.0 (evicted by: 7.1.3)
[info]   |     | +-org.scalaz:scalaz-core_2.11:7.1.3 [S]
[info]   |     | | +-org.scala-lang.modules:scala-parser-combinators_2.11:1.0.4 (evicted by: 1.0.5)

Comment: Then you introduced it yourself in your `build.sbt` or `project/*.scala` files?! Or any other plugin you are using did it?

Comment: @cbley, that is what I'm not understanding I'am not writing explicitly in the build file

Comment: What is the output of `inspect test:libraryDependencies`? Look at the "Defined at: " list which tells you where the value is coming from.

Comment: @cbley it show some files that are including any call for specs dependency.

Comment: Please add the output to the question. It is very hard to understand what you mean, I'm still only guessing. Better yet, show us your code / minimal project that reproduces the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Please try a clean-build by removing all the previous conflicting dependencies

Comment: yes I tried that but it did not resolve the problem, furthermore I tried to remove the ~/.ivy2 cache folder and rebuild but the same problem

Comment: Please use answers to provide solutions. You can suggest debugging ideas through comments on the question.